# Is there public access to a paper, in which the first $k$-tuple conjecture was proposed?

Tags: reference-request, twin-primes, distribution-of-primes

How did Hardy and Littlewood derive this conjecture and what needs to be done to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but is this what you are looking for?

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887559